# Laravel Sanctum keeps returning unauthenticated

Tags: php, laravel

**Before you mark it as a duplicate: Yes, I have tried everything out there for the past 10 hours, nothing works...**

I've tried to:

- Set session storage to cookie
- I have set, SANCTUM's stateful domain, session domains, and still the issue persists.
- I have also tried getting rid of "EnsureFrontendRequesstAreStateful" middleware as some github issues had it mentioned, and still didn't work.
- I have also tried to set SameSite to "NONE" in the config files, still same issue.
- Debugged everything on my local, and everything worked fine. Only doesn't work on production.

More details:

- Sanctum Version: 2.9.2
- Laravel Version: 8.34.0
- PHP Version: 7.4.3
- Database Driver & Version:  MySQL  Ver 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

#### Description:

I have two apps: A client on Next.js and a backend API with Laravel + Sanctum.

So basically, everything works fine on localhost.

However, I have issues making it work on production. I don't understand what I have done wrong, and I have been doing the same for a long time. For some reason, doesn't work anymore. Keep getting an "Unauthenticated" response everytime I request a resource after logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

Goto your Kernel.php, under API, set these middlewares:

```
    'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
```